# google app script fetch data from sheets within the spreadsheet into one master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a google spreadsheet containing a company data and in spread sheet i have 4 tabs(worksheets)

THE TABS(WORKSHEETS)

1. MASTER SHEET{NAME,ID,SHEET1,SHEET2,SHEET3} <COLUMN LABELS
2. SHEET1{NAME,ID,PHONE,ADRESS,TOTAL HOURS WORKED,TOTAL DELIVERIES}<COLUMN LABELS
3. SHEET2{NAME,ID,PHONE,ADRESS,TOTAL HOURS WORKED,TOTAL DELIVERIES}<COLUMN LABELS
4. SHEET3{NAME,ID,PHONE,ADRESS,TOTAL HOURS WORKED,TOTAL DELIVERIES}<COLUMN LABELS

- Master sheet [where i want to store some data from other 3 tabs]
  in master sheet i have 5 columns  eg[name,id & the column "total deliveries" from 3 of the tabs}
- the 3 tabs containing 1000 of rows and 100 of columns data
  i want some of the selected columns from 3 of the tabs .
  i want to make a scripts when it runs it gets the data from 3 of the tabs and store it in master sheet..

here i am giving the link of the spread sheet where you can see the tab "copy of master sheet" i have manually copy and pasted the data the same result i want in the master sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ysKEjxtBgtRaG0cETf2kI7GdPmIqcTaZJ8QmYmTNWzM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It could be easier to compile all data in one sheet as follows

```
function compile(){
  let result=[['id','name','date','working days']]
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().filter(sh => /^\d+/.test(sh.getName()))
  sheets.forEach(sh => {
    sh.getDataRange().getValues().splice(1).forEach(row => result.push([row[0],row[1],sh.getName(),row[4]]))
  })
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Compilation') 
  dstSheet.clear()
  dstSheet.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

then perform a pivot table

[image]

Comment: sorry your answer is unclear to me didn't get your point

Comment: take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IS_YFXWevxUPeACOd2sRNM3G5b9Vw-DVdy_QHf29yq4/copy you have 'Master Sheet' which compiles all the data and 'Pivot Table 1' which represents the data as you wish. I prefer a lightweight script of less than 10 lines of code which is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: thank you for your help but my question is when i run the script i get the selected data from the sheets into master sheet

Comment: At the beginning you expected columns 1,2 and 5 (working days) I will complete with other columns.

Comment: Where are phone and address in your sheets ? What you are asking now doesn't reflect the spreadsheet you have posted. My proposal fit your original request ans still available.